# Auto setting a field using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, tree

I have tree like data model in sqlalchemy that looks like this:

```py
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node_tbl'

    id = mapped_column(String(255), primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String(255))
    parent_uri = mapped_column(ForeignKey('node_tbl.id'), default=None)
    level = mapped_column(Integer, default=0)

    parent: Mapped["Node"] = relationship(backref='children', remote_side=[id])
```

Level here is distance to root. The root node's level is obviously 0, children of root have level of 1, grandchildren have level of 2 and so on.
Can I auto set this value on update? When I update a node and set a parent for it, it automatically update levels of child and the whole subtree of that child to the correct number. Is this possible perform this type data integrity to the sqlalchemy? Or I need to implement it my self?